# Make command says Go isn't installed but it is (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, docker, golang

I'm dealing with Go language not being installed for building Docker-Machine from source despite
it being installed and added to the `PATH`:

```
utcloud@owncloud:/usr/local/bin/docker-machine$ sudo make
/bin/sh: 1: go: not found
rm -Rf /usr/local/bin/docker-machine/bin/*
utcloud@owncloud:/usr/local/bin/docker-machine$ go version
go version go1.9.3 linux/amd64
```

What can I do with this ?

**UPDATE:**

output from `make`:

```
utcloud@owncloud:/usr/local/bin/docker-machine$ make VERBOSE=1
rm -Rf /usr/local/bin/docker-machine/bin/*
utcloud@owncloud:/usr/local/bin/docker-machine$
```

Makefile:

```
# Plain make targets if not requested inside a container
ifneq (,$(findstring test-integration,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    include Makefile.inc
    include mk/main.mk
else ifneq ($(USE_CONTAINER), true)
    include Makefile.inc
    include mk/main.mk
else
# Otherwise, with docker, swallow all targets and forward into a container
DOCKER_BUILD_DONE := ""

test: .DEFAULT

.DEFAULT:
    @test ! -z "$(DOCKER_BUILD_DONE)" || ./script/build_in_container.sh $(MAKECMDGOALS)
    $(eval DOCKER_BUILD_DONE := "done")

endif
```

Makefile.inc:

```
# Project name, used to name the binaries
PKG_NAME := docker-machine

# If true, disable optimizations and does NOT strip the binary
DEBUG ?=
# If true, "build" will produce a static binary (cross compile always produce static build regardless)
STATIC ?=
# If true, turn on verbose output for build
VERBOSE ?=
# Build tags
BUILDTAGS ?=
# Adjust number of parallel builds (XXX not used)
PARALLEL ?= -1
# Coverage default directory
COVERAGE_DIR ?= cover
# Whether to perform targets inside a docker container, or natively on the host
USE_CONTAINER ?=

# List of cross compilation targets
ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),)
  TARGET_OS := darwin linux windows
endif

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),)
  TARGET_ARCH := amd64 arm arm64 386
endif

# Output prefix, defaults to local directory if not specified
ifeq ($(PREFIX),)
  PREFIX := $(shell pwd)
endif
```

main.mk:

```
# Initialize version and gc flags
GO_LDFLAGS := -X `go list ./version`.GitCommit=`git rev-parse --short HEAD 2>/dev/null`
GO_GCFLAGS :=

# Full package list
PKGS := $(shell go list -tags "$(BUILDTAGS)" ./... | grep -v "/vendor/" | grep -v "/cmd")

# Resolving binary dependencies for specific targets
GOLINT_BIN := $(GOPATH)/bin/golint
GOLINT := $(shell [ -x $(GOLINT_BIN) ] && echo $(GOLINT_BIN) || echo '')

# Honor debug
ifeq ($(DEBUG),true)
    # Disable function inlining and variable registerization
    GO_GCFLAGS := -gcflags "-N -l"
else
    # Turn of DWARF debugging information and strip the binary otherwise
    GO_LDFLAGS := $(GO_LDFLAGS) -w -s
endif

# Honor static
ifeq ($(STATIC),true)
    # Append to the version
    GO_LDFLAGS := $(GO_LDFLAGS) -extldflags -static
endif

# Honor verbose
VERBOSE_GO := 
GO := go
ifeq ($(VERBOSE),true)
    VERBOSE_GO := -v
endif

include mk/build.mk
include mk/coverage.mk
include mk/dev.mk
include mk/test.mk
include mk/validate.mk

.all_build: build build-clean build-x
.all_coverage: coverage-generate coverage-html coverage-send coverage-serve coverage-clean
.all_release: release-checksum release
.all_test: test-short test-long test-integration
.all_validate: dco fmt vet lint

default: build

install:
    cp $(PREFIX)/bin/$(PKG_NAME) /usr/local/bin

clean: coverage-clean build-clean
test: dco fmt test-short lint vet
validate: dco fmt lint vet test-long

.PHONY: .all_build .all_coverage .all_release .all_test .all_validate test build validate clean
```

Comment: Yep, running it without `sudo` got me further. Now it's trying to delete directory that doesn't exist, so I created it so the `rm -rf` passes but it just exits out.

Comment: How did you install go? How did you add that in PATH?

Comment: @Kulfy  I installed it using `git clone` from the repo. I added it to the PATH by adding `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOBIN` to `/etc/profile` because I want to have it installed system-wide. Once I added it I rebooted for it to take effect. `GOBIN` env variable is set to `~/go/bin` where Go was unzipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `make` with `sudo`, it will inherit a bare-bones target user environment that does not include any changes to the invoking user's `PATH`

Ex. given

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: listpath

listpath:
        @echo $(shell echo $$PATH)
```

then

```
$ make listpath
/home/steeldriver/bin:/home/steeldriver/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

$ sudo make listpath
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

If possible, always `make` software in your user's own directory - that way you avoid problems with permissions and the temptation to brute-force them using `sudo`.

Comment: What's super funny is that when I tried to look for the line `rm -Rf /usr/local/bin/docker-machine/bin/*` in the directory with Atom to delete the line it didn't find it. If it's not there how it can be called then ?

Comment: Interestingly enough when I created a dummy `bin` directory so the command can delete it and carry on it just exits out probably because of permissions. I've set permissions to 777 so anything could be done to the directory and subdirectories. Yet it just exits out. Not continuing.

Comment: @Mark if the command is being issued as part of a `make` process, then you're unlikely to find the literal text anywhere. I suggest you update your question with the full output of the `make` command (or perhaps `make VERBOSE=1` if that provides more useful detail).

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Since half of the `Makefile` are just imports I'll include the other files too.

Comment: @Mark Have you tried running `make clean` and / or `sudo make clean` before trying again? It's not uncommon to have to do this after a `make` error.

Comment: @mchid  I didn't know. Thank you. It didn't help much though. Still outputs the same. No progress.

Comment: I can delete the `bin` directory with `rm -rf bin` but the `make` file exits out when the script is runs it. You go figure. I've moved the whole directory into home directory so I don't have to deal with extra permissions.

Comment: I wish I could just pull it from official repo and get on with life but this version is somewhat special and has to be compiled from source. Thus no way around this.

Comment: @Mark imho your original question has been answered - you are now asking "Why doesn't the docker-machine build process appear to work?"